# Wordpress Theme Update,showing junk characters instead of texts and images

Tags: wordpress

**[SOLVED]**

```
I SIMPLY CHANGED THE OWNERSHIP OF DIRECTORY TO THE PROCESS OWNER.
```

UPDATE:

```
FOR THOSE WHO LIKE TO CHECK DEVELOPMENT SITE,I HAVE ECHOED ALL POSSIBLE ERRORS .PLEASE CHECK.
```

I have made a development mirror site for my wordpress website [Newsyaps](http://newsyaps.com).

Everything is same.But it shows junk characters instead of contents. Here is the link for my test site:

```
http://184.72.230.144/newsyaps/
```

Things i noted:

1.When i de grade my theme to the old version,everything works fine.

2.When i check http header request at [Web Sniffer](http://web-sniffer.net/),  It shows ERROR CODE: 500.

3.When i try to validate the site here :

```
 http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2F184.72.230.144%2Fnewsyaps%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices
```

It shows:

```
Sorry, I am unable to validate this document because on line 580 it contained one or  
more bytes that I cannot interpret as utf-8 (in other words, the bytes found are not
valid values in the specified Character Encoding). Please check both the content of the
file and the character encoding indication.
The error was: utf8 "\xFF" does not map to Unicode
```

Comment: It looks to me that images are not loaded in the <img /> tag, but as inline text...

Comment: @LaurIvan is right, the binary image data seems to get embedded directly into the HTML code, instead of being referenced as external resources. As to why this happens – well, you’ll have to go and ask the guy who provides your theme resp. this update of it.

Comment: OK,i agree images are not loading as images,but why not the rest contents?

Comment: @user2277145 imho you have some code in your wordpress template to dump the content of the image when the template gets rendered (something like "read the image file and print" in the page).

Comment: @LaurIvan Ok,the first step i will take it to install a fresh copy of updated theme...and then try to tamper those codes.

Comment: @LaurIvan Thanks for your supports.But actually the error was permission issue...i changed my directory owner to the process owner and now its working..just bit confused why it didn't show any problem with older version of theme..may be few codes !

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your supports.But actually the error was permission issue...i changed my directory owner to the process owner and now its working..just bit confused why it didn't show any problem with older version of theme..may be few codes